# QT ; How can I store resources path to variable at run-time?

Tags: c++, qt

My qt project has .qrc file so my resources files are stored like ":/audio/melody/...".

I need to choose which files to use or not in runtime, so my program stores the resources path in .txt file.

In runtime, my program get these path to string, as variables.

So now I need to use these variables to put [setSource(variables)] methods of any other Qt objects. But it can't.

I tried to convert std::string (which has the file path) to QString, and put it in QtObj.setSource() as QUrl(QString).

But I found the QUrl(QString) has no data(I expected that there was resource path like ":/audio/melody/.. blahblah" in QUrl(QString)).

How can I convert the std::string(which has resource path) to QUrl, in order to use it as a resource path?

Actually, I wonder there is possibility to use resource path as variables.

Comment: So you want a list of all added resource files at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all resources, the files itself and a URL to the file at runtime you can do this:

```
QHash<QUrl, QFile> list;
QDirIterator it(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    QFile file(it.next());
    QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(file.fileName())

    list.insert(url, file);
}
```

Comment: I resolved it by using  >> setSource(QUrl::fromUserInput(path.c_str())), the 'path' variable was std::string where the resource path in. Anyway thank you for your answer!